# Simplify time-series JSON data plotted in a D3.js area chart

Tags: graph, d3.js, time-series, simplify, data-manipulation

We're displaying time series data (utilisation of a compute resource, sampled hourly over months) on a stacked area chart using D3.js:

```
  d3.json("/growth/instance_count_1month.json", function( data ) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.datapoints = d.datapoints.map(
        function(da) {
          // NOTE i'm not sure why this needs to be multiplied by 1000
          return {date: new Date(da[1] * 1000),
                  count: da[0]};
      });
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data[0].datapoints, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0,
              Math.ceil(d3.max(data.map(function (d) {return d3.max(d.datapoints, function (d) { return d.count; });})) / 100) * 100
             ]);
```

The result is rather spiky for my tastes:

[image]

Is there an easy way to simplify the data, either using D3 or another readily available library? I want to reduce the spikiness, but also reduce the volume of data to be graphed, as it will get out of hand.

I have a preference for doing this at the UI level, rather than touching the logging routines (even though redundant JSON data will have to be transferred.)

Comment: Not an answer to your question (filtering comes to mind) but here is a very nice example of smoothing time series data using [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html). It's open source built on top of D3.

Comment: You could play around with the [interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate) of the line/area you're using as a start.

Comment: @ChristopherHackett, as in, the actual recording of the data to begin with, or how it is passed to the javascript interface.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I did, but it doesn't make any real difference when there are more data points than pixels. There's nothing to interpolate.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes: Yes, that's the look I'm hoping for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options, you need to decided what is the best way forward for the type of data you have and the needs of it been used. Without knowing more about your data the best I can suggest is re-sampling. Simply report the data at longer intervals ('rolling up' the data). Alternatively you could use a rolling average or look at various line smoothing algorithms.

Comment: Sampling at longer intervals doesn't really work: let's say I always want 50 X points in the graph, regardless of the time period. You wouldn't know in advance what the sampling interval should be (and it will change).

Comment: If you always want 50 points then you are describing some sort of piecewise linear approximation of the data.

Comment: Yeah. There's probably way to use D3's interpolate functions to build a new array of 50 points from the old one. I'll see.